# Pinterest Open Graph price tag update based on a product option

Tags: jquery, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags, pinterest

Pinterest requires price tag to be present in Open Graph metas. In my case I have product options which have different prices (drop down driven options selection). HTML output for that part looks like

```
<select style="max-width:200px;" name="modifiers" id="modifiers" class="form-control">
<option value="3"> Option1 ($573.00) </option>
<option value="4"> Option2 ($291.00) </option>
<option value="5"> Option3 ($139.00) </option>
<option value="6"> Option4 ($97.00) </option>
</select>
```

Is it possible to update `<meta property="og:price:amount">` using jQuery `.change` event trigger using values which are between parenthesis?

Thanks

Comment: Would Pinterest’s parsers run JavaScript?

Comment: Yeah - that what I have figured out in a hard way :\

Answer (score 0):

We had the problem where some of our offers have no price. We offer 10% off or kids stay free or something like that. They just turned us down for Rich Pin product. But I think many companies have wanted to support their standard but they didn't think the must have price thing completely through. I was told they might revise things someday.